# IE8 throwing hasOwnProperty undefined exception with breeze.debug.js

Tags: breeze

To start with, the web application I am working with needs to work with IE8, which uses ES3 javascript standards rather than ES5. I am utilizing the [es5-shim.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) library in hopes it might help but unfortunately it does not fix the exception being thrown, preventing breeze from initializing.

Here is the block of code in breeze.debug.js that seems to be a part of the issue, if not the root where IE8 reads hasOwnProperty as undefined:

```
Enum.prototype.getNames = function() {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in this) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(this, key)) {
                if (key != "name" && key.substr(0, 1) !== "_" && !core.isFunction(this[key])) {
                    result.push(key);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have an additional exception in another .js file which calls breeze as such: `var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(window.Urls.dataModelApiUrl);`

Here breeze is read as undefined by IE8, I imagine because breeze.debug.js never initialized properly to begin with.

Any adivce/help/suggestions to help troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: additional info: for testing purposes I utilized the es5-shim tests site, which can be  found in the es5-shim link above, I included a reference to breeze.debug.js in the site and that site is throwing the same exact exception. I have been digging in to this, but no progress from me yet. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: Update:: I edited the block of code above to use "Enum.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call..." 

This seems to have solved the issue. Breeze seems to initialize as necessary and the application is working (more thorough testing to follow). To my understanding this change pulls hasOwnProperty directly from Enum.prototype rather than assuming it is already available in the space.

Although I am not sure if this is a correct solution, it is something that I tried purely out of experimentation. I will know more after I test the application to see if anything broke as a result.

Comment: Thanks for pushing through the pain. I have submitted a defect report for this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this should be fixed in v 1.1.3. Please post back if not.